# Excel VBA Pivot Table Arrayed Filtering

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I have some pivot tables that I want to apply some advanced filtering to via VBA, but I'm not sure how to go about it or if it is even possible without doing some work on the data first.

To simplify the data, the current pivot tables rows, with fields Numbers and Letters looks like:

```
1
    A
    B
    C
2
    A
    B
    C
3
    A
    B
    C
```

I would like to be able to filter the table more specifically to end up like:

```
1
    A
    B
    C
2
    A
    B
3
    A
```

I'm not sure how to even describe the process beyond arrayed filtering. I know I could manipulate the source data to reach these results, but similar things have come up frequently enough that if there is a way to do it purely through pivot table filtering, that would be a great help.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: You already have put your letters and numbers the way you want them to, what am I missing? Do you have value data as well (not shown) in your table? You could get those by calling GETPIVOTDATA(...)

Comment: There is plenty of value data in the table. The issue I am trying to solve is only having some of the letters show up under some of the numbers.If I add Numbers and Letters to the row field, it will calculate all occurances of the letter within each number. I want it to ignore specific combinations, in the above example, I do not want it show the combinations 2C, 3B, and 3C.